# Update existing data otherwise insert new data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new in laravel.First I have  I have inserted a form data into database .Then I have fetched this data into an array. Then I inserted this data into a new database. When every time insert form data, In my second database all data inserted multiple time.My code is given below:

```
foreach($result as $res) {
    $res1 = UserList::firstOrCreate($res);
 }
```

Here is my array. If same data is in database, I only want update the array new value into database

Comment: Use an if statement. Not that one.

Comment: Where will use if statement after/before firstOrCreate()

Comment: Sorry for that. Search for validation in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to use is `updateOrCreate`

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
  ['needle' => $value],
  ['field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2']
);
```

Hope this help.